# Move-item inside loop (one liner)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move some files based on a CSV list.
Here's my CSV:

```
newalias,path
tat000017.txt,tat000010.txt
```

Here's my powershell:

```
import-csv tatlist.txt | foreach {move-item -path $_.path "new\"+$_.newalias}
```

But I get this error:

> Move-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '+@{newalias=tat000017.txt; path=tat000010.txt}.newalias'.
>
> At line:1 char:30
>
> - import-csv tatlist.txt | foreach {move-item -path $*.path "new\"+$*.newalias}
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

I'm running the powershell in the same directory as *tatlist.txt*, all files are there too in that directory.

Comment: `move-item -path $_.path "new\$($_.newalias)"`

Comment: @CB. if i change to that I just get the prompt

Comment: CB is right... what prompt are you talking about? Do you need `-confirm:$false`

Comment: @Matt Indeed, I made a typo, it's working.

Comment: @CB. Thanks, it works. If you create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Cornwell Post as an answer.Glad to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment change it to:

```
move-item -path $_.path "new\$($_.newalias)"
```

You need the notation `$($myvariable.myproperty)` for having properties's variable expansion!